# Porque no puedo traer la data de mi api a mi front end?

Tags: laravel, reactjs, api, laravel-9

Estoy tratando de hacer que mi front end realizado en ReactJS interactué con mi api hecha con Laravel 9 pero por alguna razón no estoy pudiendo mostrar mi data en el componente.

Este es mi componente donde se tendría que plasmar toda mi data de la api de productos

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const endpoint = 'http://localhost:8000/api';
const ShowProducts = () => {

    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getAllProducts();
    }, [])

    const getAllProducts = async() =>{
        const response = await axios.get(`${endpoint}/products`);
        setProducts(response.data);
    }

    const deleteProduct = async(id) =>{
        const response = await axios.delete(`${endpoint}/product/${id}`);
        getAllProducts();
    }



  return (
    <div>
        <div className='d-grid gap-2'>
            <Link to="/create" className='btn btn-success btn-lg mt-2 mb-2 text-white'>Create</Link>
        </div>
        <table className="table table-striped">
            <thead className='bg-primary text-white'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            
            <tbody>
                {products.map((product)=>(
                    <tr key={product.id}>
                        <td >{product.description}</td>
                        <td >{product.price}</td>
                        <td >{product.stock}</td>
                        <td >
                            <Link to={`/edit/${product.id}`} className="btn- btn-warning">Edit</Link>
                            <buttton onClick={()=>deleteProduct(product.id)} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</buttton>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ShowProducts
```

Por alguna razon me muestra el componente con la tabla pero no me trae ninguna data, pero si yo voy al puerto donde esta corriendo mi api http://localhost:8000/api/products me muestra el json con todos mis productos.

Mi consola muestra el siguiente error pero no logro entender si es relevante con esto o no.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default().get is not a function
```

Comment: Pusiste `ìmport axios from react` jeje pequeño detalle. Por eso te dice que `get` no es una función del import default de react.

Comment: gracias, se debe haber auto completado. @FedericoMeza

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta es:

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

En vez de

```
import axios from 'react'
```